# Run second non-paginated loop on archive.php

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination, archive

I have a standard archive.php page in wordpress that lists all the posts for the given category, and adheres to the 'posts per page' set in the admin of 6.

Above this on the archive.php I'm trying to run the same loop but displaying all posts, not paginated (so I can display a map of all posts in that category, not just the 6 on that page)

I can get the loop going with the below code, but cannot get it to ignore the pagination and show all posts for the given category. Can anyone help please?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>

    Blah  

<?php } } rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try using `query_posts('category_name=your_category')` to query an array of posts using a condition. you can then run the loop again and it will use this newly created array.

You can find a detailed article on [the Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops).

Hope it helps! Cheers!